# cumulative sum for each user and sorting

Tags: mysql, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to get the cumulative sum for each user.

related tables(just example):

[user]

| id | nickname |
| --- | --- |
| A | AA |
| B | BB |

[pointTable] user_id -> [user]id

| id | user_id | point |
| --- | --- | --- |
| piA | A | 10 |
| piB | B | 8 |

[pointHistoryTable] point_id -> [point]id

| id | point_id | gain | use |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| phi1 | piA | 25 | 0 |
| phi2 | piB | 10 | 0 |
| phi3 | piA | 0 | 10 |
| phi4 | piB | 0 | 9 |
| phi5 | piB | 7 | 0 |

(For gain-use column, only one of them has a value.)

The result I want:

| nickname | current | cGainSum | cUseSum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 10 | 25 | 10 |
| BB | 8 | 17 | 9 |

The query I used(mysql v5.7):

#1

```
SELECT 
    user.nickname AS nickname,
    pointTable.point AS current,
    sub.cGainSum AS cGainSum,
    sub.cUseSum AS cUseSum
FROM
    (SELECT 
        point_id, SUM(gain) AS cGainSum, SUM(`use`) AS cUseSum
    FROM
        pointHistoryTable
    GROUP BY point_id) sub
        INNER JOIN
    pointTable ON pointTable.id = sub.point_id
        INNER JOIN
    user ON user.id = pointTable.user_id
ORDER BY cGainSum DESC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

#2

```
SELECT 
    user.nickname AS nickname,
    pointTable.id AS pointId,
    pointTable.point AS current,
    (SELECT 
            IFNULL(SUM(gain), 0)
        FROM
            pointHistoryTable
        WHERE
            point_id = pointId AND gain > 0) AS cGainSum,
    (SELECT 
            IFNULL(SUM(`use`), 0)
        FROM
            pointHistoryTable
        WHERE
            point_id = pointId AND `use` > 0) AS cUseSum
FROM
    pointTable
        INNER JOIN
    user ON user.id = pointTable.user_id
ORDER BY cGainSum DESC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

Both work. But sorting takes a long time. (20,000 users)

When sorting with `current`, #1 takes about 25s and #2 takes about 300ms.

However, when sorting by cumulative sum(`cGainSum` or `cUseSum`), #1 takes about 25s again and #2 takes about 50s.

So #1 always causes a slow query, and #2 causes a slow query when sorting by cumulative sum.

Any other suggestions?

++

I'm using this query in node api. The data is sorted by the request query. The request query can be current, cGainSum, or cUseSum.

like this...

`SELECT (...) ORDER BY ${query} DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;`

The offset uses the pagination related request query.

(included in the details)

Comment: Move (or add) sorting and limiting into the subquery - i.e. process not all but only top 20 `cGainSum` in outer query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that without all those sub queries it would run faster with just simple joins and aggregate function if I misunderstood something you are welcome to correct me, this is anyways what I came up with

```
SELECT user.nickname,pointTable.point,SUM(pointHistoryTable.gain), SUM(pointHistoryTable.use) FROM user
LEFT JOIN pointTable
ON user.id=pointTable.user_id
LEFT JOIN pointHistoryTable
ON pointHistoryTable.point_id=pointTable.id
GROUP BY user.id
ORDER BY ${query} DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

**EDIT:**

Besides improving the query, like not creating to complicated subqueries etc. A very easy way to improve performance is the use of indexes. I would for starters create indexes for all the id's in all the tables. You simple do this by using CREATE INDEX indexname ON tablename (column1,column2, etc) in your case for pointHistory the query would look something like this

`CREATE INDEX pointHistoryIndex ON pointHistoryTable ('id','point_id')`

Comment: It works well. thank you.
but it takes 30s in prod.....

Comment: @user15348043 I added another suggestion to my answer, try adding indexes to your tables